# Finite projective dimension may lead to projectiveness!

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module, injective-module

> Assume a ring $R$ is injective as an $R$-module. If the projective dimension of an $R$-module $P$ is finite could one conclude that $P$ is a projective $R$-module?

Probably one should start with a finite projective resolution for $P$, and then ...? Every free $R$-module is a direct sum of $R$ a cardinality many times. Now, how I can use the injectivity of $R$?

Comment: I think you may need a noetherian condition for this. Probably the way you are describing it will be to ensure every projective module is injective.

Comment: The noetherian case is settled in [this topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218721/global-dimension-of-quasi-frobenius-ring).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R=K^{\mathbb N}$ be a countable direct product of copies of a field $K$. (For simplicity we may suppose $K=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.) This ring is self-injective, and its global dimension is $2$. But $I=K^{(\mathbb N)}$, a countable direct sum of copies of $K$, is an ideal of $R$ which is not a direct summand of $R$, and therefore $R/I$ isn't projective.

**Edit.** For those who don't like the continuum hypothesis and stuff, let me mention that isn't necessary to assume that $\operatorname{gldim}R=2$. The ideal $I$ is countably generated in a von Neumann regular ring, so it is projective (Kaplansky). This shows that $\operatorname{pd}_RR/I=1$.

Comment: The global dimension of $R$ is not well-defined in ZFC; it may be taken to be infinite. See http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=265411